# Different IPs between sets of IP ranges

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ip, set-difference

I have two sets of multiple IP ranges. Each IP ranges is a pair of `(startIP, endIP)` in longs. So I have two sets `a` and `b` -

```
a = [(start11, end11), (start12, end12)...]
b = [(start21, end21), (start22, end22)...]
```

I wish to find the IPs which are in `a` but not in `b`. Or in other words `set(ips_a) - set(ips_b)`.

I tried brute-force of checking each IP in `a` against `b`, but the process takes forever since there are over 100 million IPs in each set.

Would like to know what would be most optimized way to do this. Also, if any existing module does this.

Comment: please add a practical example (and what you have tried ...).

Comment: you want code? I am taking each IP in each range of `a`, and checking it against each `start, end` in `b`. Just for loops.

Comment: that's not code, that's a description of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following algorithm that's `O(n log n)` with respect to the number of addresses:

- I assume that within each list, the IP address ranges have no overlap. If they do, eliminate those overlaps (merge ranges).
- Sort both lists by the start of the ranges.
- Loop using two variables, one tracking the current position in the first list, let's call it `i`, and another one tracking the current position in the second list, let's call it `j`.
- While `b[j] < a[i]`, increment `j`. That is, skip the `b[j]` that are before `a[i]`, not overlapping with `a[i]`.
- If `a[i]` overlaps with `b[j]`, remove the overlapped part from `a[i]`, and increment `i`.
- Repeat until the end of `a` is reached. As a result, all ranges in `a` that were also in `b` will be removed from `a`.

The time complexity of this algorithm is `O(n log n)` due to the sorting step.

Comment: Ahh nice! This should reduce the complexity surely. And complexity would be `O(nlogm)`, m = number of ranges? In my cases ranges are just a few thousands, I think this should be  `O(n)`

Comment: @hyades It's `O(n log n)` where `n` is the number of ranges in the longer list, whichever it is.